# Pegando imagem do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo um site em `PHP` e `MySQL` para armazenar os produtos e imagem deles. Na página dos produtos tem 5 ou mais modelos e preciso pegar 5 ou mais imagens de cada produto. Não sei se crio uma outra tabela e coloco as imagens nela ou uso a mesma tabela.
Qual alternativa vocês sugerem?

Comment: Crie uma tabela so para as imagens e você identifica ela pelo id do produto

Comment: Complementando com o comentário acima, você cria duas tabelas, uma do produto e outra das imagens, associa cada imagem ao id de um produto, assim cada produto poderá ter quantas imagens forem necessárias.

Comment: Obrigadooooooo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu usaria duas tabelas. Uma tabela contendo os dados do produto:

```
CREATE TABLE produtos(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ... suas colunas aqui.
);
```

e a outra contendo as imagens:

```
CREATE TABLE imagens(
    id_imagens INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'imagem.jpg',
    id_produtos INT NOT NULL,
    ... outras colunas contendo o que quiser aqui,
    CONSTRAINT dados_imagens_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_produtos)
    REFERENCES produtos(id)
);
```

Com isso, você consegue armazenar quantas fotos quiser para cada produto, depois só precisa buscar esses dados na tabela de imagens pelo id do produto. Pode usar um INNER JOIN se quiser(é o que eu normalmente uso).

```
SELECT p.nome AS nome, i.nome AS nome_imagem 
FROM produtos AS p 
INNER JOIN imagens AS i 
ON p.id = i.id_produtos;
```

Dependendo da sua aplicação, eu recomendo armazenar apenas o nome da imagem + a extensão dela no banco de dados e criar uma pasta só pro caminho dela. Ah, seria bom também não deixar o nome original da imagem, normalmente quando vou usar upload de arquivos com PHP, eu dou um base64_encode() no nome do arquivo e pedo os primeiros 32 caracteres, assim nas buscas fica mais fácil e mais organizado(na minha opinião).

Links úteis:

- [Joins](http://angelitomg.com/blog/tutorial-basico-sobre-joins/)
- [Relacionamento de tabelas no MySQL](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql)
- [Inner Join SQL - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Crie duas tabelas para facilitar,uma de imagens e a outra de produtos e você pode associar o id da imagem com o id dos produtos.

Aqui vou colocar somente um exemplo,você não precisa tomar como base,é simplesmente para você ter uma noção.

Cria primeiro uma tabela para armazenar as imagens :

```
create table images (
    image_id        tinyint(3)  not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    image_type      varchar(25) not null ,
    image           blob        not null,
    image_size      varchar(25) not null,
    image_ctgy      varchar(25) not null,
    image_name      varchar(50) not null
);
```

Depois disto,cria uma tabela de produtos(vou só colocar o id de produtos só para exemplo) :

```
create table products (
products_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT
);
```

Depois disto você pode associar com a tabela produtos o id da imagem com o id do produto :

```
select image_id from images join products on images.image_id = products.products_id;
```

> OBS : No inner join você coloca caso quiser `where` para fazer uma condição para estas associações.

Comment: Obrigadooooooo!